# How to generate new import code following a structure change in an upstream flat file without headers?

Tags: sas

I have an existing process that imports data from a flat file with no headers. There are hundreds of columns. The provider of the file has added several hundred more columns at different points within the existing columns. I have a list of the old and new column names and SAS code that properly sets the data types for the old columns but not the new ones. I'd rather not have to go through my existing import code and manually write column headers and data formats but I'm not sure how to use these parts to get new import code for the new headers.

```
data raw_file;
infile "flatfile.csv" delimiter="|" missover dsd firstobs=1;
informat oldcol1 best32.;
informat oldcol2 mmddyy10.;
informat oldcolN $60.;
format oldcol1 best32.;
format oldcol2 mmddyy10.;
format oldcolN $60.;
input
oldcol1 
oldcol2 
oldcolN $;
run;
```

I have the header information in an Excel file right now.

 `old  K010H K010I   K010J                          K020A
 new  K010H K010I   K010J   K010L   K010M   K010N  K020A`

Comment: Can you show example of the LISTs.  If I understand correctly you need to change you process to read the list (meta data) and code gen the data step to read the file.

Comment: I added an example of how I am seeing the difference in headers.

Comment: Is there any pattern for assigning attributes to new column names based on old column names ?  For example, is this statement appropriate ? *all `K010<letter>` columns should have the same attributes*

Comment: I think there is but there are a lot of new columns so that may not be the case for all of them.

Comment: @BenjaminCrane how do you determine data type and INFORMAT for for each column?

Comment: It's legacy code so I'm not sure how they got the initial list of variables and formats. For the new columns I have examples of individual forms so where I can't copy from existing column formats I'll probably have to determine it manually.

Comment: @BenjaminCrane are you saying the "provider" did not supply a document that lists each field and relevant attributes?

Comment: They gave me the list of headers but no other attributes or metadata. Not my favorite upstream provider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I presume you either know or will find out the informats for the new columns also. If that is the case, why  don't you auto generate the code to read the file?

Since you have the header information, assuming you can modify it to the following format and save as a CSV:

```
var     infmt
K010H   best32.
K010I   mmddyy10.
K010J   $60. 
K010L   best32.
K010M   mmddyy10.
K010N   $60. 
K020A   best32.
```

Then something like this would automatically generate the code and read the data for you:

```
proc import datafile="cols.csv" out=cols replace;
run;

proc sql;
  select var into :cols separated by ' ' from cols ;
  select infmt into :infmts separated by ' ' from cols ;
  quit;

%macro gen_code;

  data raw_file;
    infile "flatfile.csv" delimiter="|" missover dsd firstobs=1;

    %let ii = 1;
    %do %while (%scan(&cols, &ii, %str( )) ~= %str());
      %let col = %scan(&cols, &ii, %str( ));
      %let infmt = %scan(&infmts, &ii, %str( ));
      informat &col &infmt ;
      %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);
    %end;

    input
    %let ii = 1;
    %do %while (%scan(&cols, &ii, %str( )) NE %str());
      %let col = %scan(&cols, &ii, %str( ));
      &col 
      %let ii = %eval(&ii + 1);
    %end;
   ;
 run;

%mend;

%gen_code;
```

In the future, you could make modifications to your header CSV file and the rest will be taken care by the code itself.

Comment: This was pretty much what I was looking for. I like that I'll be able to make changes more easily should they pull a major change like this in the future.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a machine readable data dictionary then you can generate the code from that. Otherwise you will need to just edit your data step.  While you are at it you can clean it up so that it is easier to maintain.

First thing is to use LENGTH or ATTRIB to define the variables, instead of forcing SAS to guess.  Second only attach informats or formats to variables that need them.  For example there is no need to attach informats to normal strings or numbers. No need to attach $xx format to character variables.  Do you really need to attach BEST32. format to numbers instead of letting SAS go ahead and display the numeric variables without formats attached using the default BEST12. format?

Second if you define the variables in the order they appear then you can use a positional variable list in the INPUT statement.  Then you only have to change the INPUT statement if the first or last variable changes.

So for your example you might create a data step like this instead.

```
data raw_file;
  infile "flatfile.csv" dlm="|" truncover dsd firstobs=1;
  length 
     oldcol1 8
     oldcol2 8
     oldcolN $60
  ;
  informat oldcol2 mmddyy10.;
  format oldcol2 mmddyy10.;
  input oldcol1 -- oldcolN ;
run;
```

Then adding new variables is as simple as inserting them into right place in the LENGTH statement and when needed adding them to the INFORMAT and/or FORMAT statements.  If you don't know what the variables contain then make them as character strings and look at the resulting values and decide later if you need to define them differently.

Comment: Helpful info, especially about ways to improve the data step and make it more SAS appropriate.